# Encoding problem in Java while reading data from site/page:

Tags: java, encoding

During writing automated test i have one problem.
While I reading data from database or from page i have problem with polish diacritics chars.
For example

> 30-09-2019 15:43:51 INFO [Log]: Wnioskodawca AutoNawa wysĹ‚aĹ‚/-a wniosek.
>   30-09-2019 15:43:51 INFO [Log]: {{#pl}}**{{loggedUser.fullName}}** utworzyĹ‚/-a szkic wniosku.{{/pl}}> {{#en}}**{{loggedUser.fullName}}** created application draft.{{/en}}

It should be Wnioskodawca AutoNawa wysłał/-a wniosek etc.

Do You know how to this this issue?
I tried to add suffix useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8 on db connection line, but it not works for me

Comment: Your problem is how you log it or how you fetch it? Where do you need them to be correct?

Comment: I want to assign texts from database/site to variable and use it to assertions